# How to implement quick-run aliased commands for a docker-compose running container?

Tags: bash, shell, docker, docker-compose

I have a `docker-compose.yml` config file, which is launched by `docker-compose up` just fine.

Now, as the structure of the app gets more complex, I want to be able to run some tasks inside the running instance.

I know I can land into the container by `docker exec -i -t <container_id> /bin/bash` then run some shell commands there.

Is there a way to link some '.sh' file inside the container and run it, e.g. like `docker-compose runscript updatedb.sh`? What are other options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place your scripts inside the container, and run them with docker-compose.

Let's say your `docker-compose service` is called `myservice` and you put a script called `script1.sh` with execute permissions in the `/scripts` folder, you can run something like this from your host:

```
docker-compose exec myservice /scripts/script1.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

docker-compose exec it the only way to execute something inside a container, so anything that needs to execute on a ruuning container needs to use this command.

The solution is to create a bash funtion in your `.bash_rc` profile, something like:

```
docker-exec-sh(){
    docker exec -it "$1" "$2"
}
```

And then from command line you can run:

```
docker-exec-sh <container-id> <shell-script-executable>
```